# How do I create an Audit Trail using Triggers in PHPMyAdmin on a shared hosting platform?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I found this really great way to create triggers..
https://www.simple-talk.com/author/pop-rivett/

but I think this is only using sql server.. I am looking for a way to audit my very small (3mg) database to show every table change, who changed what, when, and where and maybe if they put in a note, why.  :)

Please let me know if you have the code to create a "trigger" using the phpmyadmin sql tab or trigger creator to insert the code?? I am not really a coder at all just learning php and mysql over the last few months.  Any help is most appreciated.  I run a small non profit and are looking to track tagged manatees, and turtles and sharks in our database and want to 'dummy' proof the data against dummys who may make bad changes to the data.

Please help it is a good cause!

Thanks, Tina

Comment: You are going to get a wide variety of opinions on this. Some people (like myself) believe that application functionality should reside primarily in the application layer, meaning that you should implement code to add such auditing (and perhaps wrap everything in a transaction, depending on how stringent your auditing needs are). Other who may have more of a DBA background might prefer to utilize triggers for this. For someone just learning, I would probably suggest you focus your efforts on learning PHP rather than DB triggers as your learnings there will likely be more widely applicable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `AuditUserTrigger`
       BEFORE UPDATE ON `Users`
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    INSERT INTO `aUsers`
         SELECT `Users`.*
           FROM `Users`
           INNER JOIN `AuditTables`
                   ON `AuditTables`.`name` = 'Users'
                  AND `AuditTables`.`enabled` = 1
          WHERE `Users`.`id` = OLD.`id`;
  END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

**EDIT**

By way of an explanation:

I have an Audit table defined as

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `AuditTables` (
  `id` int(12) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `enabled` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `auditTable` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 
;
```

which contains an entry for every core table in the database, together with the active flag that can be set to true or false (1 or 0) depending on whether I want that table to be audited or not.

For my `Users` table (as shown in the original example) I have a corresponding audit table (`aUsers`) with an identical structure, but without unique keys, that can hold all the "historic" records from the `Users` table. The ON UPDATE trigger on `Users` will save the OLD `Users` table record to `aUsers` if auditing is enabled for the `Users` table ***before*** executing the actual UPDATE against the user record.

All records in all tables also have the following columns:

```
`archived` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`createdAt` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`createdBy` int(12) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
`updatedAt` datetime ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`updatedBy` int(12) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
```

giving me details of who an when updates were done, while the `archived` flag is set as a "soft delete"

`createdBy` and `updatedBy` are managed by my code, with an element in my model layer that automatically injects the session user ID into that property.

`updatedAt datetime ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,` requires MySQL 5.6

Comment: Mike Brant, thanks.. I researched this for weeks and you are right, many different opinions.. as my php is weak and the app I used to create the database (AppGini.com) is great.. I prefer not to screw it up.. I think if I do this at the database level I am much better off, plus once I learn to do it at this level it will save me hours doing it later on other apps I have.

Comment: Mark, to make sure I understand, if my audit table is named audit my table that I want to track changes to is called compliance then my code should look like this???     DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `AuditUserTrigger`
       BEFORE UPDATE ON `compliance`
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    INSERT INTO `audit`
         SELECT `compliance`.*
           FROM `compliance`
           INNER JOIN `AuditTables`
                   ON `AuditTables`.`name` = 'compliance'
                  AND `AuditTables`.`enabled` = 1
          WHERE `compliance`.`id` = OLD.`id`;
  END$$   What is inner join for? 
DELIMITER ;

Comment: Mark, What is the audit tables in there for?  That refers to? Is that the name of the table for the audit?? I am just a bit confused on the code after FROM.. can you explain it a little?   Thanks so much for your help.  I am grateful!

Comment: Mark, Sorry to sound a bit thick.. can you dumb this down a bit.  My app allows me to duplicate a table and rename it.. so I can do the atable name thing mentioend, I also already have fields like $memberInfo['userid'] that I can use to pull the user name and $data['LastUpdated'] which shows who and when the last update happened.. trapping the old data and new data (just the data that is changed is the tricky part for me.)   Can you explain what each part does in your code.. or what specifically I need to change..   so where you have YOUR TRACKED TABLE NAME ??? I would put My atablename?

Comment: My method doesn't save only the data that was changed to the audit table, it stores the entire original record to the audit table

Comment: Mark I like this.. One last question.. can I input this code into the triggers.. in phpmyadmin?   Or will this option only work in sql server??   Thanks again!

Comment: You should be able to execute the create trigger in phpMyAdmin, though I tend to execute a script file from the command line